# I'm looking for Russian books on topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

I wanna read topology (General, Algebraic, Differential, Geometry) books written by Russians. It can be advanced or intermediate level. <3 Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for Russian *language* texts? If not, why exactly do you want the author to be Russian? Also, what is your background?

Comment: @Noah I think it's clear that Luis is looking for text(book)s written in Russian.  Perhaps he is learning Russian for a language requirement in his math program, and to do this, needs to be able to translate from Russian to English...Maybe he hopes to teach in Russian....maybe he wants to be bilingual, maybe he speaks Russian?  I Think this question can be answered adequately regardless of any specifically identified purpose.

Comment: Luis is already, it seems, at an advanced or intermediate level in the subjects in question. He obviously can communicate in English, likely another language.  There is no reason not to name a good reference of two of texts/sources, which happen to be written in Russian?

Comment: See [this entry in Wikipedia which includes a (not exhaustive) list of mathematicians in Russia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Russian_mathematicians).  I would scroll through the list carefully to make note of areas of publication, areas of research, etc.  Perhaps, if your question survives, someone well versed in Russian can better offer specific texts.

Comment: Asking for books by Russian authors, the edition [Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences](http://link.springer.com/bookseries/855) immediately skips to mind. AFAIK it is published both in English (by Springer) and [in Russian](http://www.viniti.ru/russian/math/itogi/fund.htm ) (by VINITI) and it includes several volumes on topology. For example, three volumes on general topology which I mentioned in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118190/reference-for-general-topology/138821#138821).

Comment: Do you simply want (one of the) authors of the book to be Russians? That seems odd. Or do you simply want books with Russian versions? Or maybe those which were originally in Russian? Please clarify.

Answer (score 10):

I have made a short list of books that came first to my mind. It is very far from being complete, I will probably take time to expand it, if needed. I included some books that exist both in Russian and English. I give Russian titles, if you are interested in the original versions.

Some of them are not advanced (e.g. Viro-Ivanov-Netsvetaev-Kharlamov and *Intuitive Topology* by Prasolov), but you will hopefully see it from their titles and tables of contents. I also tried to add links to MatSciNet reviews.

- Viro, Ivanov, Netsvetaev, Kharlamov, *Elementary topology. Problem textbook* [[MR2444949](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2444949)] (Виро О. Я., Иванов О. А., Харламов В. М., Нецветаев Н. Ю., *Задачный учебник по топологии*)
- Prasolov, *Intuitive Topology* [[MR1310779](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1310779)] (В. В. Прасолов, *Наглядная топология*)
- Vassiliev, *Introduction to Topology* [[MR1816237](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1816237)] (Васильев В.А., *Введение в топологию*)
- Rokhlin, Fuchs, *Beginner’s Course in Topology* [[MR0759162](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0759162)] (Рохлин В.А., Фукс Д.Б., *Начальный курс топологии*)
- Fomenko, Fuchs, *Homotopical Topology* [[MR0873943](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0873943)] (Фоменко А.Т., Фукс Д.Б., *Курс
  гомотопической топологии*)
- Prasolov, *Elements of Homology Theory* [[MR2313004](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2313004)] (Прасолов В. В., *Элементы теории гомологий*)
- Prasolov, *Elements of Combinatorial and Differential Topology* [[MR2233951](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2233951)] (Прасолов В. В., *Элементы комбинаторной и дифференциальной топологии*)
- Novikov, Fomenko, *Basic Elements of Differential Geometry and Topology* [[MR1135798](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1135798)] (Новиков С.П., Фоменко А.Т., *Элементы дифференциальной геометрии и топологии*)
- Fomenko, Mishchenko, *A Short Course in Differential
  Geometry and Topology* [[MR2531914](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2531914)] (Мищенко А.С., Фоменко А.Т., *Краткий курс дифференциальной геометрии и топологии*)
- Dubrovin, Fomenko, Novikov, *Modern Geometry ― Methods and Applications* [[MR0736837](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0736837), [MR0807945](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0807945), [MR1076994](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1076994)] (Дубровин Б.А., Новиков С.П., Фоменко А.Т., *Современная геометрия, Методы и приложения*) — I think there also exist French, Spanish, and Italian translations
- Postnikov, *Lectures in Geometry* [[MR0890748](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0890748), [MR0887104](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0887104), [MR938953](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=938953), [MR0685757](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0685757), [MR1824853](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1824853)] (Постников М.М., *Лекции по геометрии*)
- The volumes *General Topology [I](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-61265-7_1), [II](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-77030-2), [III](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-07413-8)* (for original texts, check [mathnet.ru](http://www.mathnet.ru/))
- The volumes *[Topology I. General Survey](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-10579-5)* (translation of a survey by Novikov; see the original Russian text [here](http://mi.mathnet.ru/intf70)) and *[Topology II. Homotopy and Homology. Classical Manifolds](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-10581-8)* (translations of surveys by Viro and Fuchs; original Russian texts: [1](http://mi.mathnet.ru/intf100), [2](http://mi.mathnet.ru/intf101), [3](http://mi.mathnet.ru/intf71))

Personally, I recommend the very last item, which is a collection of great surveys, and one of my favorite books ever is *Homotopical Topology* by Fomenko and Fuchs, which also comes with some mind-blowing [drawings made by Fomenko himself](https://estetico.me/posts/view/grafika-anatolija-fomenko).

[image]

Comment: As soon as I saw this question I thought 'someone has to have mentioned Fomenko'!

Comment: @Anon Fomenko has published many books and he's famous for various activities, but one thing is for sure: the book he wrote with Fuchs is one of the best texts on algebraic topology.