# More comprehensive General Topology's book than Engelking

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, reference-works

Other than [Engelking General Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3885380064), I also come across other graduate general topology text such as [Dugundji](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0697068897) and [Kelley](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387901251), which I also find them interesting.

However, I find Engelking's book more comprehensive compare to the two graduate texts.

> Question: Does there exist a general topology book which is more
>   comprehensive than Engelking? If yes, what is the title?

Comment: Some of the books listed as answers to this question might be of interest: [Reference for general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/118190). (As you can see, there is already an overlap between the suggestions given in the answers.)

Answer (score 5):

I'm a fan of "Handbook of Set-theoretic Topology", which I often use, and Engelking as well. It contains many things that are more recent than Engelking and is more research oriented.

Nagata's "Modern General Topology" is also nice. Also in the Japanese school "Topics in General Topology", by Morita and Nagata. The latter book is more like the Handbook. The first more of a text book, like Kelley or Dugundji (which are good as well).

Comment: Just a small question about Engelking: are there significant differences between the first (1977) and the second edition (1989)? Moreover, is the 1968 book "Outline of General Topology" just the first translated version of the same topics or is it a different book? Thanks!

Comment: @SonGohan I'm not sure. I only have the 1989 translation. I cannot judge the difference from the original Polish one. In the foreword he does mention that the '88 edition is much updated (better proofs, more uptodate with research, errors removed etc. more exercises)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, no. There are big general topology books “Topology” by Kuratowski (available at LibGen) and “Handbook of set-theoretic topology” (eds. Kunen and Vaughan) (also available in the Internet), but they consider selected topics.

Answer (score 3):

I like *General Topology* by Willard for reference of difficult theorems.
It is point set topology orientated instead of analysis orientated.

Comment: Are you suggesting that Willard's text is _more_ comprehensive than Engelking's?

Answer (score 2):

When looking for a result, Engelking is my first choice. But, as [my recent experience](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265141/is-mathbbr-mathord-sim-hausdorff-if-x-y-x-sim-y-is-a-closed-su/2392314#2392314) shows, one should also not miss Bourbaki.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that Bourbaki is indeed very comprehensive. However, Its volume 4 (chapter 5-9) is not available as ebook at springer anymore.