# Is there a name for this type of topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ be a topology on $X$ such that for every $a, b$ in $X$ there exists a bijective function $f$ that is continuous and has a continuous inverse such that $f(a) = b$.

Examples of such a topology:
the topology induced by the euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^n$
the discrete topology, the trivial topology

non examples:
$\tau = \{\emptyset,a,\{b,c\},X\}$ where $X = \{a,b,c\}$

Is there a name for these type of topologies?

Comment: It seems that such spaces are called [*homogeneous*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25326/homogeneous-topological-spaces).

Comment: yes that appears to be what I want, thank you, feel free to write that as an answer to the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Sangchul says in the comments, such spaces are called **homogeneous**. An equivalent way to phrase the definition is that the group of homeomorphisms $X \to X$ acts transitively on $X$. Important examples include

- any connected manifold (this is not obvious)
- any topological group $G$
- any quotient $G/H$ of a topological group by a subgroup.

The term "[homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space)" is also used for something more specific, namely a pair consisting of a space $X$ and a topological (sometimes Lie) group $G$ acting transitively on it.