Topological spaces $X$ satisfying: for arbitrary $x, y \in X$, there exist a homeomorphism $f: X \to X$ sending $x$ to $y$.
I wonder for what kind of topological spaces $X$ the following assertion is true: given any $x, y \in X$, there is some homeomorphism $f: X \to X$ such that $f(x) = y$. I have just learnt that all topological groups satisfying the condition above; and I think that there might be other spaces possessing this property, maybe some closed connected surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (not sure about that). Can anyone give me some examples?

Such topological spaces are called homogeneous. In group theory terminology it means that the group of homeomorphisms $X\to X$ acts transitively on $X$. As for examples, it can be shown that all connected manifolds are homogeneous. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89721/are-all-connected-manifolds-homogeneous

Duplicata: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25326/homogeneous-topological-spaces
