# Homogeneous topological space with the fixed-point property

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, fixed-point-theorems, homogeneous-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space. $X$ is said to be homogeneous if for every $x$ and $y\in X$ there is an self-homeomorphism $f$ of $X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Further, $X$ is said to have the fixed-point property if every endomorphism of $X$ has a fixed-point. My question is:

> Is there a example of a topological space which has the fixed-point property but is also homogeneous (that isn't the one-point space)?

The only examples of fixed-point spaces I know are compact, convex subspaces of Euclidean space which are guaranteed by the Brouwer Fixed-Point Theorem. These spaces are not homogeneous since we cannot drag a boundary point into the interior by a homeomorphism. The examples I know of homogeneous spaces are topological groups and unit spheres neither of which have the fixed-point property.

I attempted to show the properties are incompatible, but there doesn't seem to be an inherent contradiction in the two properties. I do know that topological groups do not have the fixed-point property, so those are out of the search. But other than that, my search into an example or a proof of incompatibility has been fruitless.

Any help either way is appreciated.

Comment: The unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ doesn't have the fixed-point property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard example is the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$. It is homogeneous by a theorem of Keller: see [Why is the Hilbert Cube homogeneous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2194) for a discussion. It has the fixed-point property by [Schauder's fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed_point_theorem).

Answer (score 5):

A smaller example is $\mathbb{CP}^2$. It's homogeneous since $GL_3(\mathbb{C})$ acts transitively on it and has the fixed point property by the [Lefschetz fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem).

More generally, if $G$ is a Lie group and $H$ a closed subgroup of it, then $G/H$ is a homogeneous smooth manifold. This is a rich class of spaces which includes, for example, the spheres and the real and complex projective spaces as special cases. See [symmetric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space) for more examples.