# Does every homogeneous space allow a group structure?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a [homogeneous space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space), that is for all $x,y \in X$ there is a homeomorphism $\varphi:X\to X$ such that $\varphi(x) = y$. Is there a group operation $*:X\times X\to X$ such that $(X,*,\tau)$ is a topological group?

Comment: Note that homogeneous space often means that there exists a transitive continuous action of a *connected Lie group*, which is much more restrictive than your definition: for instance all connected topological manifolds are homogeneous in your sense, but for instance closed surfaces of genus $\ge 2$ are not homogeneous in the stronger sense. Anyway the answers provide counterexamples that are homogeneous in the stronger sense, such as the 2-sphere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily.

It can be shown that every connected topological group has Euler characteristic $0$. Now take the $2$-sphere, for example. It is connected, and the Euler characteristic $\neq0$. It is homogeneous, of course.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to get negative answers: a topological group does not have the fixed point property (every map from $X$ to itself has a fixed point), as a translation $x \rightarrow a\ast x$ with $a \neq 1$ does not have a fixed point.

But there are homogeneous compact metric space with the fixed point property, e.g. the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2194/4280) for reasons why this is so.

Comment: And a complete proof that the Hilbert cube is homogeneous can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1363), with explicit homeomorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

$S^2$ is a classical counter-example. See Corollary 9.59(iv) on p. 486 in

> K.H. Hofmann and S.A. Morris, *The Structure of Compact Groups*, Berlin, 1998.

Let me give you a method of producing non-separable examples. By [Tkachenko's theorem](http://boolesrings.org/mpawliuk/2013/05/06/using-dushnik-miller-to-prove-that-every-sigma-compact-group-is-ccc/), any $\sigma$-compact group is ccc. So consider homogeneous $\sigma$-compact spaces which are not ccc. You can construct such spaces by taking countable unions of certain (open) long lines.